# AgentExecutor and ModuleNotFoundError/NameError

Tags: python, langchain

`AgentExecutor` should be able to install python packages.

Here is code snippet:

```
from langchain.agents import ConversationalChatAgent, AgentExecutor 
from langchain.agents import Tool
from langchain.agents import create_pandas_dataframe_agent
from langchain.chat_models import AzureChatOpenAI


#df = pd.read_csv(...)
#llm = AzureChatOpenAI(...)

agent_analytics_node = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(

 llm, 
 df, 
 verbose=True, 
 reduce_k_below_max_tokens=True, 
 max_execution_time = 20,
 early_stopping_method="generate", 

)

tool_analytics_node = Tool(

 name='Analytics Node',
 func=agent_analytics_node.run

)

tools = [tool_analytics_node]


chat_agent = ConversationalChatAgent.from_llm_and_tools(llm=llm, tools=tools)


executor = AgentExecutor.from_agent_and_tools(

 agent=chat_agent,
 tools=tools,
 return_intermediate_steps=True,
 handle_parsing_errors=True,
 verbose=True,

)



prompt='can you help understand mood of customers'

response = executor(prompt)
```

Here is the current output from the agent:

```
> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
Thought: The question seems to be asking for the sentiment polarity of the 'survey_comment' column in the dataframe. The sentiment polarity is a measure that lies between -1 and 1. Negative values indicate negative sentiment and positive values indicate positive sentiment. The TextBlob library in Python can be used to calculate sentiment polarity. However, before applying the TextBlob function, we need to ensure that the TextBlob library is imported. Also, the 'dropna()' function is used to remove any NaN values in the 'survey_comment' column before applying the TextBlob function.
Action: python_repl_ast
Action Input: import TextBlob
Observation: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TextBlob'
Thought:The TextBlob library is not imported. I need to import it from textblob module.
Action: python_repl_ast
Action Input: from textblob import TextBlob
Observation:
Thought:Now that the TextBlob library is imported, I can apply it to the 'survey_comment' column to calculate the sentiment polarity.
Action: python_repl_ast
Action Input: df['survey_comment'].dropna().apply(lambda x: TextBlob(x).sentiment.polarity)
Observation: NameError: name 'TextBlob' is not defined
```

Also `TextBlob` is installed in python environment .

Comment: The posted code does not refer to `TextBlob`.  Therefore the error must happen elsewhere.  Please post the full error traceback message, so we can see where the error actually happens.

Comment: @JohnGordon There is no TextBlob in code. `executor` is getting a question from user 'can you help understand mood of customers' and it decide by its own what to do next and what packages to import

Comment: it complains about TextBlob install it -> `pip install -U textblob`, don't know what `agent_analytics_node.run` source is. so can only suggest installation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with AzureOpenAI, also the results with agent executor is not consistent. These are all knows issues. In order to make this work consistently you need to modify your code as below. I am not using memory because it was not clear from your code what you were doing..

```
        from langchain.agents import ConversationalChatAgent, AgentExecutor 
        from langchain.agents import Tool
        from langchain.agents import create_pandas_dataframe_agent
        from langchain.llms import OpenAI
        import pandas as pd

        folder_path = "./documents/"

        df = pd.read_csv(folder_path+"Corona_NLP_test.csv")
        llm = OpenAI(model_name='text-davinci-003', temperature=0)

        agent_analytics_node = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(
                                                                llm, 
                                                                df, 
                                                                verbose=True, 
                                                                reduce_k_below_max_tokens=True, 
                                                                max_execution_time = 20,
                                                                early_stopping_method="generate", 
                                                            )



        tool_analytics_node = Tool(
                                        name='Analytics Node',
                                        description="Useful tool for data anlysis from dataframe",
                                        func=agent_analytics_node.run)

        tools = [tool_analytics_node]


        chat_agent = ConversationalChatAgent.from_llm_and_tools(llm=llm, tools=tools)

        executor = AgentExecutor.from_agent_and_tools(
                                                                agent=chat_agent,
                                                                tools=tools,
                                                                handle_parsing_errors=True,
                                                                return_intermediate_steps=True,
                                                                verbose=True,
                                                                max_iterations=1
                                                                
                                                            )


        prompt='can you help understand mood of customers'

        response = executor({"input":prompt, "chat_history":[]})
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for provided answer but it is not what I am looking for. I want the agent to be able import and use python packages and if those installed in python environment. For example instead of asking "analyze customer sentiment" try to ask directly:  "analyze customer sentiment with TextBlob". In this case agent would try import it but for some reason I am getting `Observation: NameError: name 'TextBlob' is not defined` even if it is in my python environment